# Print .rtf or .txt file from PRINT button?

Tags: c#

I am making a simple work note pad test program. I want to be able to click on a menu item in the menutool bar (Print) and have the document print to my printer. The following code is what I use but I am not sure if this is all that I need for a simple print. I am new to C# and thus not complete familiar with the printDocument class.

```
private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


       try 
       {
           StreamReader streamToPrint = new StreamReader
              ("C:\\My Documents\\MyFile.txt");
           try 
           {
              Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
              PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
              pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(myFileName);
              pd.Print();
           }  
           finally 
           {
              streamToPrint.Close();
           }
       }  
       catch(Exception ex) 
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not handling the `PrintPagEvent` properly.

**Solution :** to print the document you need to handle the `PrintPageEvent` properly by writing the `PrintPageEvent` Handler.

```
    String content="";  
    Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
    private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try 
       {
              content= File.ReadAllText("C:\\My Documents\\MyFile.txt");
              PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
              pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
              pd.Print();
       }  
       catch(Exception ex) 
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       } 
    }
     private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
     {
       ev.Graphics.DrawString(content,printFont , Brushes.Black,
                       ev.MarginBounds.Left, 0, new StringFormat());
     }
```

Comment: The only error that I receive now is that the Access to the Path is Denied. I receive this error on any directory or drive that I use. Also if I want to save the directory so that the user can print from any file on any location it would be best if the file was open in the rich text box because a person would really print a document that wasn't open already. I changed it so that it just reference myFile and not a directory and it works. Thank you for the help.

Comment: try 
           {
               content = File.ReadAllText(myFileName);
               PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
               pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler    (pd_PrintPage);
               pd.Print();
           }